# MySQL select specific date from datetime

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup a mysql select query based on a given date in a datetime column. Something like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') WHERE..
```

But I'm unsure on how to do this correctly. I'm using php to do this.

Comment: Your query seems right. Please provide more information.

Comment: Well I don't know how to finish it. Should it be like this? WHERE colName='2014-04-08'?

Comment: Well it depends on what do you want to get? `SELECT DATE_FORMAT()` is only formatting data for display, where `WHERE` condition is used to select what do you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following example explain the query to select date between 01-Jan-2014 and 15-Jan-2014.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') AS colName
FROM 
    `my_table` 
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-01-01' AND DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2014-01-15'
```

Comment: Why bother with `DATE_FORMAT()` in the `WHERE` clause?  Why not `... WHERE colName >= '2014-01-01' AND colName < '2014-01-16'`?

Answer (score 0):

To verify your query, use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35166) and use a query without any table such as

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') from dual
```